# google maps v3 fill in circle completely

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geometry

I created a map which allows users to draw a circle around a point with a specified radius. For some reason the circle does not get completely filled in and this is especially noticeable when the map is more zoomed in. Perhaps someone has a solution to fill the circle completely even when viewed at at a higher zoom level

See code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
 <style type="text/css">  
    html { height: 100% }   
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }  
    #map_canvas { height: 100% } 
 </style> 
<script type="text/javascript"   
 src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> 
 </script> 


</script>
<script type= "text/javascript">

   var geocoder;   
    var map;  
    var count=0;
    //Store points in array 
    var points = [];



function initialize() {    
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();     
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);    
    var myOptions = {       
    zoom: 3,      
    center: latlng,       
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP    
   }     
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);  
}    
function codeAddress() {    
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {       
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {         
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);        
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({          
        map: map,             
        position: results[0].geometry.location
        }); 

    }
     else {        
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);       
    }     
    });   
    }
function plusCount(){
if (count==2){
count=0;
}
else{
count=count +1;
}
}   

function drawCircle() {
var address=document.getElementById("address").value;
var radius=document.getElementById("radius").value;
var latitude=40;
var longitude=0;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status){
if (status==google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
latlng=(results[0].geometry.location);
latitude=latlng.lat();
longitude=latlng.lng();
alert(latitude);
alert(longitude);
alert (radius);
}   

else{
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
}
});





//Degrees to radians 
  var d2r = Math.PI / 180;
  alert("calc d2r " + d2r);
 //  Radians to degrees
 var r2d = 180 / Math.PI;
 alert("calc r2d " + r2d);
// Earth radius is 3,963 miles
 var cLat = (radius / 3963) * r2d;
alert("calc cLat " + cLat);
 var cLng = cLat / Math.cos(latitude * d2r);
   alert("calc cLng " + cLng);




  // Calculate the points
  // Work around 360 points on circle
 for (var i=0; i < 360; i++) {

   var theta = Math.PI * (i/16);

   // Calculate next X point 
   circleY = longitude + (cLng * Math.cos(theta));            
    // Calculate next Y point 
   circleX = latitude + (cLat * Math.sin(theta));
    // Add point to array 
    points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(circleX, circleY));


 };


    alert("completed loop");

    var colors=["#CD0000","#2E6444","#003F87" ];

    var Polyline_Path = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: points,
   strokeColor: colors[count],
    // color of the outline of the polyline
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    // between 0.0 and 1.0
   strokeWeight: 1,
   // The stroke width in pixels
   fillColor: colors[count],
    fillOpacity: .5
   });
    Polyline_Path.setMap(map);


 }

function clearMap(){
if(points){
for( i in points){
points[i].setMap(null);
}
points.length=0;

   }}


</script>
</head>
    <body onload="initialize()"> 
       <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:460px;
       -moz-outline-radius:20px; -moz-box-sizing:padding-box; -moz-outline-      style:solid ;-moz-outline-color:#9FB6CD; 
    -   moz-outline-width:10px;"></div>  
        <div>     
        Zip Code: <input id="address" type="textbox" value="">    
        Radius:<input id="radius" type="textbox" value="">
        <input type="button" value="Find" onclick="codeAddress() ">   
        <input type="button" value="Draw Radius" onclick= "drawCircle() ; plusCount()">
        <input type="button" value="Reset" onclick= "clearMap()">
    </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are drawing the circle manually, but you could use the 
[google.maps.Circle](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Circle) 
which works for me and fills the circle entirely. Here is a snippet I use in my application, which works also in maximum zoom level:

```
var circ = new google.maps.Circle({
    'center':lc,
    'clickable':false,
    'fillColor':"#00FFFF",
    'fillOpacity':0.2, 
    'map':currentmap,
    'radius':75, 
    'strokeColor':'#0000A0',
    'strokeOpacity':'0.5'
});
```

*lc* is my center point, *currentmap* is the map div

Comment: I tried substituting map_canvas for currentmap and latlng for lc but it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me

```
var options = {
    strokeColor: #CD0000,
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: #2E6444,
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    map: map,
    center: latlng,
    radius: parseInt(radius)
};

var circle = new google.maps.Circle(options);
```

Comment: i got it to work, but how do you convert translate radius the user entered into miles?

Answer (score 0):

```
var drawInnerZone=
        {
            strokeColor: "#61A0A8",
            strokeOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            fillColor: "#61A0A8",
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
            map: map,
            center: NearMatches['InnerZone'].center,   //Latlng
            radius: NearMatches['InnerZone'].Distance  //radius
        };  
MatchZone1 = new google.maps.Circle(drawInnerZone);
```

it works for me..

Answer (score 0):

the answer for richie work correctly on my project

```
function searchLocations() {
     var image='image/male.png'
     var a = document.getElementById("radiusSelect").value; 
     var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        icon: image
    });
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
         map: map,
          radius: parseInt(a),    // 10 miles in metres
         fillColor: '#AA0000'
            });
    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
    searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
   } 
   else {
     alert(address + ' not found');
   }
  });
 }
```